# how to remove 3 lines in row if the first line contain a specific character?

Tags: regex, r, row

I have a data file (which a matrix with 290 lines and 2 columns) like this:

```
# RIR1
ABABABABABABABABAA
ABABABABABABABABBA
# WR
ABABABABABABABABAB
BABABBABABABABABAA
# BR2
ABABABABABABABBABA
ABBABABABABABABABA
# SL
AAABABABABABABBABA
AAABBABABABABABABA
```

I would like to remove all the data that are for SL and WR (as example). So I will have only:

```
# RIR1
ABABABABABABABABAA
ABABABABABABABABBA
# BR2
ABABABABABABABBABA
ABBABABABABABABABA
```

I know how to remove one line that start or contain something but no idea how to do with 3 lines in row.

this is what I use for one line:

```
old<-old[!substr(old[1,],1,5)=="# BR2",]
old<-old[!substr(old[1,],1,6)=="# RIR1",]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the class and structure of `old` ? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: its a `matrix` and structure is `chr [1:290, 1:2] "96" "#" "1" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to remove the unwanted part.

```
txt <- '# RIR1
ABABABABABABABABAA
ABABABABABABABABBA
# WR
ABABABABABABABABAB
BABABBABABABABABAA
# BR2
ABABABABABABABBABA
ABBABABABABABABABA
# SL
AAABABABABABABBABA
AAABBABABABABABABA'
```

Then to remove section for `WR` you can use `gsub` as below. (Note: `cat` command is used only to print out the result

```
cat(gsub('(.*)(# WR.*?)(#.*)', '\\1\\3', txt))
```

The output will be

```
# RIR1
ABABABABABABABABAA
ABABABABABABABABBA
# BR2
ABABABABABABABBABA
ABBABABABABABABABA
# SL
AAABABABABABABBABA
AAABBABABABABABABA
```